# FIFA 14 PS4 Career Mode Virtual Pro Low Match Ratings

Tags: fifa-14

I have consistently low match ratings when playing my striker.  Even in games where I get a goal or two or an assist or two my ratings will stay sub 7.0.  I never have any successful 1 on 1 or key dribbles despite stats at the end of the match saying I complete most of my dribbles.  I even get the skill boosts for beating players off the dribble.  Occasionally out of nowhere I'll get a 9+ contributing the same stats as any other game.  Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: So I partly figured it out last night.  I started demanding the ball more.  Passing and running all over the pitch.  I found this greatly boosted my score.  I guess I wasn't doing enough at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I partly figured it out last night. I started demanding the ball more. Passing and running all over the pitch. I found this greatly boosted my score. I guess I wasn't doing enough at first.

Answer (score 2):

Ratings in FIFA for strikers aren't solely based on how often you score. There are several factors:

- Goals
- Assists
- Number of successful passes
- Percentage of shots on target
- Key passes
- Dribbling
- Positioning

So if you shoot 10 times to get 1 goal, that will reduce your rating.

Comment: I have been paying attention to these stats.  I seem to get less touches in FIFA 14 than previous iterations.  I've been playing the series for a whlie and getting a good match rating was usually not a problem.  I should also add that I've already exceded my season objectives and usually meet my upcoming fixtures objectives, but still end up with low match ratings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be linked to the in-match team tactics set by your coach.

If it's 'defensive', doing your job as a striker and staying in position for counter attack will make your match rating drop down steadily even after 5 goals and 5 assists... If it's 'offensive' during the whole match you can get 9.8 as a striker just by staying in position and passing the ball.

You can try to make the coach switch to 'offensive' by being overly aggressive at every counter attack occasion, maintaining successful attack situations with a lot of passing in opponent territory, but that's the only way.